# How to Init empty array of MutableLiveData inside AndroidViewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I try to create a viewModel that serve an array of string.
But when i try to do .postValue to my LiveData object i got this error.

```
Array initializer is not allow here.
```

My viewModel is like this.

[image]

So how can i fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this way: `((MutableLiveData<String[]>) this.filterTastes).postValue(new String[]{});`

Answer (score 1):

That's for initializing variables. You can create empty array with `new String[0]`